# Activity или Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity

Разрабатываю приложение типа онлайн-магазин. По нажатию на товар в списке пользователь должен увидеть окошко, в котором есть фото товара, подробное описание и кнопка "в корзину". Что лучше для это использовать - активити или фрагмент (или еще что-то)?
 Необходимо, чтобы по возвращению к списку товаров этот список оставался в прежнем состоянии (прокрутка, вкладки), и желательно, чтобы список не пересоздавался, так как он достаточно тяжелый, может вызывать подтормаживания

Answer (score 1):

Лучше фрагмент он легче, по сути они вроде мини активити.